# Isolate commit history to specific branch

Tags: git

Say, I have an empty repository with a single initial commit:

```
* - Initial commit (master)
```

Then I create a `develop` branch locally and make a few commits on it. But before I push it to remote (without merging it with master yet) I update `master` with `remote` which brings a few commits as well to `master` branch and I get this:

```
*   - Update something (master)
| * - Make some changes to the new feature (develop)
| |
* | - Make some changes (master)
| * - Add new feature (develop)
|/         
* - Initial commit (master)
```

So, my question is how can and should I, after I push `develop` branch to the remote, how I can merge `develop` with `master` branch as a single commit without copying any of the history of `develop` branch to `master`, but keep all the history on `develop` branch.

Comment: You shouldn't do this. If you do, `master` and `develop` will have diverged and will no longer (easily) merge in the future. You also won't be able to (easily) tell that you've done this, as `git branch --merged` will not consider `develop` to have been merged into `master`.

Comment: Are you trying for a squash?  There are caveats and warnings with that... http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html

Comment: This is kind of a "you should understand this yourself before you do anything in git" kind of question. I recommend reading lots more tutorials. I'm not trying to be rude or dismissive, but it is like a "git 101, barrier to entry" sort of thing. If you don't yet understand what your options are here, there will be too many other things you either can't do in git, or you will do wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that you can't, quite—but you *may* be able to do what you *want*, and the main problem here is a bunch of ways Git does (and talks about) things that are weird and different, with fiddly technical definitions (which people get wrong too often, which just adds to the confusion).

## Lots of background (sorry, it's kind of long)

Let me redraw your commits horizontally (which works better for text articles on StackOverflow), and give them one-letter names:

```
A--C--E   <-- master
 \
  B--D    <-- develop
```

That is, `A` is the initial commit, `C` and `E` are the two additional commits that are currently "on" (findable from) branch `master`, and `B` and `D` are the two commits you made that are "on" (findable from) `develop`.

Here's a trick question: which branch is commit `A` on?  `master`, or `develop`?

It's a trick question because in Git, it is on *both* branches.

#### Branch names and reachability

In fact, the *names* `master` and `develop` are nearly irrelevant.  What matters are the commits.  The names, which I've drawn over towards the right, merely point to *one specific commit*.  We call that one specific commit the *tip* of the branch, and then we—and Git—work backwards, using the parent information stored in each commit, to find earlier commits.

These parent links, `E` back to `C` back to `A`, or `D` to `B` to `A`, only go one way: from child, to parent.  They're all backwards from the way we might expect at first, and they determine which commits are *reachable* from any given commit.  Starting from `C`, we can reach `C` itself (of course) and also `A`; and that's all.  Starting from `E`, we can reach `E`, `C`, and `A`—and that's the complete contents of the branch, `master`, since `master` points to commit `E`.  Starting from `D`, we can reach `D`, `B`, and `A`; and since `develop` points to `D`, that's the complete contents of the branch `develop`.

But this means that commit `A` is on *both branches*.  That's just the way Git is: a commit is on any number of branches—even none, sometimes—and the set of branches is based on *reachability*, through the parent links in each commit.  The *names* merely serve to get us started in the graph, and there are names other than branch names, such as tag names.  Let's put in two new temporary commits, `F` and `G`, just for illustration:

```
     tag: T
        |
        v
        F--G   <-- tempbranch
       /
A--C--E   <-- master
 \
  B--D    <-- develop
```

Now commit `G` is find-able through `tempbranch`; commit `F` is find-able by its tag `T` *and* through `tempbranch`, and commits `A-C-E-F-G` are all on `tempbranch`.  Let's now delete the *name* `tempbranch` entirely:

```
     tag: T
        |
        v
        F--G
       /
A--C--E   <-- master
 \
  B--D    <-- develop
```

Now we have an interesting case: commit `G` is no longer reachable at all.  Commit `F` is still reachable, via the tag `T`.  Git will eventually *garbage-collect* commit `G`, making it go away for real.  Until then, if you have saved its hash ID somewhere, you can still view it, or even "resurrect" it by giving it a branch or tag name.  (Git also keeps these IDs saved in things called *reflogs*.  There's one for each reference—such as branch and tag names—and one for `HEAD`.  These keep commits around for 30 days by default, even after removing their names.)

If we delete the tag `T` as well, commit `F` becomes eligible for garbage collection as well, and eventually we go back to the five commits we had before.  Meanwhile, since `F` and `G` are not *visible*, you won't see them: Git will act as if they're not there, unless you dig up their hash IDs somehow.

#### Merge commits

With all that out of the way, let's take a look at regular, ordinary merges.  A *merge commit*, in Git at least, is just like any other commit, with one exception: it has two or more parents, instead of just one.  (Most merges just have two, and there's nothing particularly useful about three-or-more-parent merges.)

Let's look at what happens with a regular merge that merges `develop` into `master`, in terms of the commit graph:

```
A--C--E--F   <-- master
 \      /
  B--D-´   <-- develop
```

The name `develop` continues to point to commit `D`, but the name `master` now points to the new *merge commit* `F`.  Commit `F` points back to *both* commits `E` *and* `D`.

When Git does reachability computations, it follows *all* the parent links (simultaneously, as it were).  So at this point, every commit in the graph is on branch `master`.  Commits `A-B-D` are (still) on `develop`, and if you `git checkout develop` and write a *new* commit, the new commit will only be on `develop`, with the *name* `develop` automatically moving to point to the new commit:

```
A--C--E--F   <-- master
 \      /
  B--D-´--G   <-- develop
```

This is the normal way to handle these things.  The *tree* (working-tree copy) that goes with commit `F` incorporates the changes from `B` and `D` into `master`: Git takes commit `A` vs commit `E` to find the changes from `master`, and `A` vs `D` to find the changes from `develop`, and combines them to make `F`.  Then it records both `E` *and* `D` as `F`'s parents, so that the merge remembers which commit was merged.

## Squash "merges" (end of background)

With all that out of the way, we can now talk about Git's so-called "squash merge".  You get these by running `git merge --squash`, and then doing a bit more.  Specifically, you have to also run `git commit` afterward.

A squash merge is not actually a merge at all.  If we draw the after-effect, we get this graph:

```
A--C--E--F   <-- master
 \
  B--D   <-- develop
```

The *contents* of commit `F` are the same as what we would get with a real merge.  The new commit goes on `master` as usual, i.e., `master` gets moved to point to the new commit.  The key difference is that the new commit *does not* point back to the merged-in commit, but *only* to the previous tip of `master`.

At first, this seems to be just what you want.  It does, however, have one very big drawback.  Let's add some new commits to `develop`:

```
A--C--E--F   <-- master
 \
  B--D----G--H--I   <-- develop
```

Now, when we want to incorporate the changes from `G-H-I` into `master`, we need to merge again.  If we had a *normal* merge—so that `F` pointed back to `D` as well as to `E`—Git would know how to do this.  Without a real merge, though, Git will wind up going all the way back to the common commit `A` again, and compare `A`-vs-`F`, and then `A`-vs-`I`, to try to combine the two changes.

But we already have the `B-D` changes!  They're in `F`.  If we had a *real* merge, Git would know that, and not have to figure this out.

If we're lucky—which we often are—Git figures this all out anyway.  The longer the chain of commits gets, though, with more and more changes, the less and less likely it becomes that Git will figure this out on its own.

Hence, the usual rule for squash merges is that we should make them *only* if we're going to *abandon* the merged branch, e.g., delete the name `develop` entirely.  Once we delete the name, the unreachable commits eventually get garbage-collected.

## What to do instead, maybe

When you use a real merge, the drawback is that you see everything, because of the way Git follows both parents simultaneously.  That is, if you run:

```
git log master
```

you will see all of `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, and `F` (intermixed and sorted by date, normally, though you can control this).  However, there's a very important feature to avoid this.  You can run:

```
git log --first-parent master
```

instead, to view commits without following any of the "extra" parents from merges.  This `--first-parent` view will show you *only* commits `A-C-E-F`, skipping `B-D`.  This is because `--first-parent` limits the graph traversal to skip the second parents of each merge commit.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the proper workflow would be, since you have not pushed `develop` yet, to *rebase* `develop` on top of `master` after updating `master`.

```
git checkout master
git pull

git checkout develop
git rebase master
```

Now you can push, since `develop` content is based on (and validated with) the latest `master` content.
You resolve any conflict (from replaying `develop` on top of `master`) locally first, then you push.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new single commit on `master` containing all the changes introduced by `develop` using `get merge --squash`, and then committing the results.

`merge --sqauash` will apply all the changes from `develop` to the index, and prepare a commit message containing all the concatenated commit messages from `develop`, but it will **not** create a commit. It's up to you to then `git commit` and edit the prepared commit message.

Comment: Is there a way to handpick commits I need to squash if there's one between them that I want to keep? Because usually, I do `squashing` by `git reset --soft HEAD~2, `2 is the last 2 commits`.

Comment: @Katherine: you can always use `git rebase -i` to *copy* commits to new (slightly different) variants, rearranging their order, for instance, or squashing particular ones together. Because these are new copies (with new hash IDs), this is best done only on *unpublished* (never-pushed) commits.